# phpunit set value of logIncompleteSkipped from command line

Tags: php, logging, phpunit

In our process automation, we execute phpunit to run tests against the codebase.  Due to the specifics of the requirements, the output log file is specified via a parameter (and not in phpunit.xml) - phpunit is run as follows:

```
phpunit -c ${buildDir}/phpunit.xml --group ${testGroup} --log-junit ${reportsDir}/out-phpunit.xml
```

This works well, except it does not include skipped tests into the report.  If the output report was specified in phpunit.xml, I would have included

```
<logging>
    <log type="junit" target="output-logfile.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="true"/>
</logging>
```

Unfortunately, this is not possible due to external process controlling and assigning locations dynamically.

I tried including this in the phpunit xml:

```
<logging>
    <log type="junit" logIncompleteSkipped="true"/>
</logging>
```

Yet, this did not make a difference. So, how can I tell phpunit *from the command line* to log skipped tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHPUnit documentation say that [the *logIncompleteSkipped* attribute has no equivalent command-line option](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.0/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.logging).

Maybe can you generate a `phpunit.xml` file dynamically before executing PHPUnit ? Or move the tests log file after the tests execution ?